# App quality Android vs IPhone ? The Reasons behind it?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

So started recently experimenting with the Android SDK and eclipse IDE and during this time I have found it very hard for various reasons to develop applications the main ones being

Poor emulator makes it hard to see your applications current state as its slow and buggy and often takes an age to load up.

Steep learning curve for xml based views and lack of consistency in application architecture.

Lack of support for dynamic web based applications

I have no experience of iPhone development but how does this compare and does this relate to the better quality of apps on the iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no experience of iPhone development but how does this compare and does this relate to the better quality of apps on the iPhone

Just in terms of quality of apps in the store, Android has no approval process, and Android has a cheaper sign up fee, so anyone, literally, can make anything and put it up on the Market. Also, the ever changing OS features and variety of phones also makes it more difficult for an otherwise good app to be "good" on all phones.

Good developers can make amazing apps equal to or better than what is on the iPhone, but both use a completely different language from one another, so the dev part of the question is somewhat relative to your dev. experience.